# Sex and human's sexual urge.

Tags: reproduction, human-physiology, human-evolution, sexual-reproduction

Why is it necessary for humans to feel pleasure while having sex? Why is it that other animals don't need to experience it? Is it evolutionary ? Why do we mate for pleasure when it's so energy wasting/ time consuming?

Comment: How do you know other animals don't like sex?

Comment: @user137 I know animals like to have sex as well but they do it only for reproduction and not for pleasure. Only certain species do it for pleasure. I know this kinda sound taboo but I'm curious about this

Comment: How do you reconcile your two assertions "animals like to have sex" and "they do it ... not for pleasure"? Seems contradictory to me. How well do you think, say, a dog understands its own reproductive biology? Is the dog thinking "I must propagate my species" while copulating?

Comment: http://biology.stackexchange.com/users/29114/solanacea I mean that's their instincts to reproduce

Comment: @TheoneandonlygreatK Wouldn't enjoyment of something be a great way for an evolutionary process to "enforce" an instinct? What other options are there? Withdrawal/relief from a negative stimulus can also be somewhat pleasurable/enjoyable: i.e., drinking or eating when you are thirsty/hungry.

Comment: Plenty of animals have sex for pleasure, dolphins and porcupine are known masturbators. your assumptions are just wrong.

Answer (score -2):

This is logical question and somehow related to evolution.
See mating is pleasurable to most of animals
Second thing during course of evolution mating became pleasurable not because humans can take pleasure but to attract them towards mating therby increasing population of a species helping it to survive.